# How to set the starting position for table in pdf generated by iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp and CSharp for creating the pdf.I am creating many tables.So i need to position each tables in different location.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry..I dont know what is the property to set the position for table.I used totalwidth property for table width then there is property for horizontal alignment.But i need to set the x,y position in pdf for table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code because the original pdfptable automates it's position:

```
        Private mywriter As PdfWriter
        Dim Theight = Table.CalculateHeights
        Dim DirectC As PdfContentByte = mywriter.DirectContent
        Dim templ = DirectC.CreateTemplate(Table.TotalWidth, Theight)
        Table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0.0F, Theight, templ)
        Dim myimage = Image.GetInstance(templ)

        Dim CenterH = (Doc.Top + Doc.BottomMargin) / 2

        Dim NewPosH = CenterH - myimage.Height / 2

        Dim CenterW = mywriter.PageSize.Width / 2
        Dim NewPosW = CenterW - myimage.Width / 2

        myimage.SetAbsolutePosition(NewPosW, NewPosH)
        DirectC.AddImage(myimage)
```

This Code positions the table in the middle of the page. Beware: The coordinate system begins in the LOWER left, not in the upper left.
Its vb.net code, but adaption should not be too hard.

Comment: One additional warning: You probably need to set the tablecolumn width, or calculatewidth will not work as exptected...So I understand the piss-poor "documentation"...